# Getting specific information of installed app with Swift

Tags: swift

Is there anyway to get specific information of an installed app with Swift?
I have managed to get list of installed app but I need to get the information such as copyright, created date etc..

The code to get all installed app list is this.

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let urls = fileManager.urls(for: .applicationDirectory, in: .allDomainsMask)

    do{
        for i in 0..<urls.count{
            let url = urls[i]

            if url.path == "" || !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: url.path){
                continue;
            }

            // https://hcn1519.github.io/articles/2017-07/swift_file_manager
            var appList = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: url.path)

            for j in 0..<appList.count{

                let filePath = url.appendingPathComponent(appList[j]).path
                let attributes = try fileManager.attributesOfItem(atPath: filePath)
                var fileSize = attributes[FileAttributeKey.size] as! UInt64

                //if you convert to NSDictionary, you can get file size old way as well.
                let dict = attributes as NSDictionary
                fileSize = dict.fileSize()

                var b = ""
            }

            var a = ""
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error access directory: \(error)")
    }
```

Comment: Show the code you're using to get the list of installed apps, please.

Comment: @matt added the code

Comment: Okay, so you already know about getting a file's attributes, in particular its size. Here are some other attributes you can get: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/fileattributekey